# thyristor latching and holding current confusion

Tags: transistors

i am a bit confused between the terms latching and holding current of thysristor. I know that latching current is the minimum current required to maintain the thyristor in on state after it is turned on and gate pulses have been removed while the holding current is the minimum current to maintain the thyristor in the on state. i need to know what is the state of thyristor in between the latching and the holding current.

Answer (score 3):

The latching current is associated with turning on the thyristor, the holding current to turning off.  If the current through the load is not large enough the thyristor will not turin on correctly and will turn off as soon as the load is reduced.

The holding current is the current required to maintain conduction once it is established with 0 gate current.

Here is one site that gives a good description:

[Description of latching vs holding current](http://aueeestudents.blogspot.com/2015/01/what-is-difference-between-holding.html) 
[image]